# Can I use a external Bluetooth Adapter on an Android Tablet without internal bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I bought this Android 4.0 tablet but apparently it doesn't have internal bluetooth. I would like to ask if its possible to connect an external bluetooth device so that I can transfer my files from my laptop to the tablet.

Comment: Do you *really* want to transfer files over Bluetooth? The speed is not going to be great, nor the connection reliable. I'd rather use something like [Air Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) which can be used over a Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Please add more info about your device. To answer in advance: most probably you're out of luck (I guess the bluetooth stack is just switched off for your tablet even if there's the possibility to add a bt usb stick)

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other two responses, I'd venture that if the tablet is low-end enough to not include Bluetooth internally, then it's not going to be able to handle an external adapter well or at all.  I'd also second the recommendation for airdroid.  Wifi is much more ubiquitous as a form of connectivity for devices, be they laptops, tablets, or desktop PC's.  Why futz with Bluetooth when you already have a workable solution?